# Winapi - changing window style ,some macros cause window to not display at all

Tags: c++, winapi

I am coding a simple desktop application with winapi, and when I input Window style in WNDCLASSEXW object or in CreateWindowExW function using macros some of them cause my window to not display at all. Here is a code that I use for my object and code of the function.
Numerical 0 works but those don't work for example:
WS_CAPTION WS_SYSMENU WS_MINIMIZEBOX WS_MAXIMIZEBOX

What is the fix so that I can disable resizing?

```
wcex.style
```

is where I input.

```
ATOM MyRegisterClass(HINSTANCE hInstance)
{
    WNDCLASSEXW wcex;

    wcex.cbSize = sizeof(WNDCLASSEX);

    wcex.style          = WS_OVERLAPPED;
    wcex.lpfnWndProc    = WndProc;
    wcex.cbClsExtra     = 0;
    wcex.cbWndExtra     = 0;
    wcex.hInstance      = hInstance;
    wcex.hIcon          = LoadIcon(hInstance, MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDI_WINDOWSPROJECT1));
    wcex.hCursor        = LoadCursor(nullptr, IDC_ARROW);
    wcex.hbrBackground  = (HBRUSH)(COLOR_WINDOW+1);
    wcex.lpszMenuName   = MAKEINTRESOURCEW(IDC_WINDOWSPROJECT1);
    wcex.lpszClassName  = szWindowClass;
    wcex.hIconSm        = LoadIcon(wcex.hInstance, MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDI_SMALL));

    return RegisterClassExW(&wcex);
}
```

And function code:

```
HWND g_Htext = CreateWindowExW(
        0,                              // Optional window styles.
        L"STATIC",                     // Window class
        L"Learn to Program Windows",    // Window text
        SS_LEFT,            // Window style

        // Size and position
        CW_USEDEFAULT, CW_USEDEFAULT, CW_USEDEFAULT, CW_USEDEFAULT,

        NULL,       // Parent window    
        NULL,       // Menu
        hInstance,  // Instance handle
        NULL        // Additional application data
    );
```

Comment: the style member in the WNDCLASSEX is for class styles ( beginning with CS_ ,read the documentation about them). 
Window styles can be used with CreateWindow.

Comment: Ok, thanks but how to make my main window not resizeable then?

Comment: by using wndstyles (and optionally  extstyles) parameters when creating the window

Comment: Could you give me a link? I can't find anything about wndstyles.

Comment: You are registering one window class, but then show code that instantiates a different window class. I feel there's a lot missing in this question.

Comment: assuming you're using visual studio: place the cursor on CreateWindowEx and press F1.

Comment: BTW ,wnstyles and extstyle used by CreateWindowEx are heavilly dependent on windowclass being used !

Answer (score 0):

Whether you want to disable resizing? If so , I sggest you could try to remove the `WS_THICKFRAME` style from the window style when the CreateWindow function is called.

Here is my code:

```
WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW^ WS_THICKFRAME
```

Comment: @Cahir7 
Have you got any updates? If your case has been solved, please help to mark answers. If not, just feel free to contact us. Your understanding and cooperation will be grateful.